# How to quick find word in English-words-list?

Tags: python, string, search

I have word "somewhat" or "qqqw" and want to find it in a list of words of English (it exists or not, in the list).
If I have `list of str`, then

```
is_exists = s in english_list
```

This method is slow if we have a huge list of words. i think some kind of data Structure or Algorithm is needed to make this quicker and more efficient

So how do i go about this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer in other topic. Sorry i didn't find it first.

I need to use `bisect` module and function `bisect_left`. It can quick find an item in list, sorted list.
It is fast on huge list.

Comment: I'm Glad to hear that you resolved your problem yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some nice comparison:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

What You need is probably a set.

Answer (score 1):

As has been suggested a creating a `set` rather than a `list` would be quicker.
For a "small" file of data, `list` appears to be quicker but once the file gets to a large size, accessing the `set` becomes quicker than the list.
Test it with something like this:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import sys
try:
    lookfor = sys.argv[1]
    pass
except:
    print "Program requires an word to look for"
    sys.exit()
wordset = set()
wordlist = []
with open("your file name","r") as f:
    for i in f.readlines():
        wordset.update(i.split())
        for x in i.split():
            wordlist.append(x)
def testwords(word):
    start= timer()
    if word in wordset: print ("Yes word found")
    else: print ("No word not found")
    end= timer()
    print ("Wordset",str(len(wordset)))
    print (start,end,(end - start)*1000)
    start= timer()
    if word in wordlist: print ("Yes word found")
    else: print ("No word not found")
    end= timer()
    print ("Wordlist",str(len(wordset)))
    print (start,end,(end - start)*1000)

testwords(lookfor)
```